# Animate the overflow property

Tags: css, overflow, css-animations, keyframe

I need to animate height, and set `overflow: hidden` for the first keyframe, and `overflow: visible` (and keep it) for the last one.

I'm trying this, but at the end, `overflow` is still `hidden`.

How can I solve this issue?

The 2 includes are merely SCSS polifill mixins.

```
@include keyframes(open) {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    height: $main_menu_height;
    overflow: visible;
  }
}


#main-menu-box {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;

    &.opened{
       @include animation('open 200ms ease-out 0s 1 normal forwards');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use AnimationEvent listeners. Here's my raw implementation:

**CSS**

• 2 animations (open, close)

• 2 classes (opened, closed)

• 2 states (overflow hidden/visible)

opened and closed are always toggled at animationstart, while hidden/visible states are differently worked out on animationend.

Note: you'll see a #main-menu element: it's an UL with transitioned translations on y-axis, because the whole thing is a menu slide-down/up effect.

```
    @include keyframes(open) {
       0% {
         height:0;
       }
       100% {
         height:$main_menu_height;
       }
    }

    @include keyframes(close) {
       0% {
         height:$main_menu_height;
       }
       100% {
         height:0;
       }
    }


 #main-menu-box{
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:0; // js

    &.closed{
        @include animation('close 200ms ease-out 0s');
    }

    &.opened{
        @include animation('open 200ms ease-out 0s 1');

        //#main-menu{
        //  @include translate(0, 0);
        //}
    }

    &.overflow-hidden{
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }

    &.overflow-visible{
        overflow-y:visible;
    }
 }
```

**JS**

• hamburger is a simple on/off button

• for now I had to use both jquery and vanilla selectors..

```
function poly_event_listener(element, type, callback) {
    var pfx = ['webkit', 'moz', 'MS', 'o', ''];
    for(var i=0; i<pfx.length; i++) {
        if (pfx[i] === '') type = type.toLowerCase();
        element.addEventListener(pfx[i]+type, callback, false);
    }
}

var hamburger = $('header .hamburger');
var main_menu_box = $('#main-menu-box');
var main_menu_box_std = document.querySelector('#main-menu-box');
var init_menu = true;

hamburger.click(function(){
  if(init_menu){
    main_menu_box.addClass('opened');
    init_menu = false;
    return;
  }

  main_menu_box.toggleClass('opened closed');
});

poly_event_listener(main_menu_box_std,'AnimationStart',function(e){
  main_menu_box.addClass('overflow-hidden');
  main_menu_box.removeClass('overflow-visible');
});

poly_event_listener(main_menu_box_std,'AnimationEnd',function(e){

  // in all the other cases I want hidden:true, visible:false
  // if class == closed, since animationend comes after animationstart, the state will already be hidden:true, visible:false
  // so non need to check for 'closed' here
  if(main_menu_box.hasClass('opened')){
    main_menu_box.addClass('overflow-visible');
    main_menu_box.removeClass('overflow-hidden');
  }
});
```

This works for me.

Comment: Could you include a snippet, or a fiddle?

Comment: Also, this is an old post, not sure it's still the really really best/top-notch solution. Maybe, but I should investigate.

Comment: I just want to see it in action!  :)

Answer (score 2):

In most modern browsers, [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) (prefixed with `-webkit-` in Safari) is an animatable property which can sometimes be used as an alternative to `overflow`.

Given the original example, the closest way to use `clip-path` to emulate flipping `overflow` on the last frame would look something like this:

```css
@include keyframes(open) {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    clip-path: inset(0);
  }
  99.99999% {
    clip-path: inset(0);
  }
  100% {
    height: $main_menu_height;
    clip-path: inset(-100vh -100vw);
  }
}

#main-menu-box {
  clip-path: inset(0);
  height: 0;

  &.opened {
     @include animation('open 200ms ease-out 0s 1 normal forwards');
  }
}
```

Since this animation is a simple linear animation it could even be replaced with a regular CSS transition:

```css
#main-menu-box {
  clip-path: inset(0);
  height: 0;
  transition: clip-path 0s ease-out, height 200ms ease-out;

  &.opened {
    height: $main_menu_height;
    clip-path: inset(-100vh -100vw);
    transition-delay: 200ms, 0s;
  }
}
```

However, there are two notable differences between `clip-path` and `overflow` which make it not suitable in all cases.

First, unlike an element with `overflow: visible`, an element with any `clip-path` has a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), so the way that overflowing content is rendered will be different—though in the case of a menu with overflowing content, you probably wanted this anyway!

Second, unlike `overflow` which only clips children, `clip-path` clips the *entire* element. This means if you have borders, box shadows, etc., those are going to get clipped, too. Depending upon the design of the container, this can sometimes be worked around by applying the clip to a child wrapper element instead.